# Pandas Count Group Number

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

Given the following dataframe:

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'col1':['A','A','A','A','A','A','B','B','B','B','B','B'],
                'col2':['x','x','y','z','y','y','x','y','y','z','z','x'],
                })
df

    col1    col2
0   A       x
1   A       x
2   A       y
3   A       z
4   A       y
5   A       y
6   B       x
7   B       y
8   B       y
9   B       z
10  B       z
11  B       x
```

I'd like to create a new column, `col3` which classifies the values in `col2` sequentially, grouped by the values in `col1`:

```
    col1    col2    col3
0   A       x       x1
1   A       x       x1
2   A       y       y1
3   A       z       z1
4   A       y       y2
5   A       y       y2
6   B       x       x1
7   B       y       y1
8   B       y       y1
9   B       z       z1
10  B       z       z1
11  B       x       x2
```

In the above example, `col3[0:1]` has a value of `x1` because its the first group of `x` values in `col2` for `col1 = A`. `col3[4:5]` has values of `y2` because its the second group of `y` values in `col2` for `col1 = A` etc...

I hope the description makes sense. I was unable to find an answer partially because I can't find an elegant way to articulate what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's my approach:

```
groups = (df.assign(s=df.groupby('col1')['col2']   # group col2 by col1
                    .shift().ne(df['col2'])        # check if col2 different from the previous (shift)
                    .astype(int)                   # convert to int
                   )   # the new column s marks the beginning of consecutive blocks with `1`
          .groupby(['col1','col2'])['s']           # group `s` by `col1` and `col2`
          .cumsum()                                # cumsum by group
          .astype(str)
         )

df['col3'] = df['col2'] + groups
```

Output:

```
   col1 col2 col3
0     A    x   x1
1     A    x   x1
2     A    y   y1
3     A    z   z1
4     A    y   y2
5     A    y   y2
6     B    x   x1
7     B    y   y1
8     B    y   y1
9     B    z   z1
10    B    z   z1
11    B    x   x2
```

Comment: If its not too much trouble, could you provide a brief explanation of how this works for my own education? I think I have it about 80% figured out but would love to hear your breakdown :)

Comment: @Paul3349 see if the added comments help.